# How to update <script> tags Dynamically in VB asp.net Stripe Checkout

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, stripe-payments

How can we manage and update Data-Amount and description programmatically from code behind page?

Suppose I have lable1 for Data-Amount and Label2 for description the details will be getting from query string.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" id="PayScript" class="stripe-button"  data-key="<%= stripePublishableKey %>" data-amount="500" data-name="Stripe.com" data-description="Sample Charge" data-locale="auto" data-zip-code="true">
</script>
```

Comment: *Suppose I have lable1 for Data-Amount and Label2 for description the details will be getting from query string.* -- then can you show what you have done so far for your code behind -- i.e. through the point where you have fetched the results via the query string?  The more code you can show, the greater the chance that someone can step in and help you finish the remainder.  See [ask].

Comment: If you are just beginning, [How to integrate Stripe payment gateway to ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62749790/3744182) and the pages to which it links may help you get started.